# to_json not working in javascript for mongoid object in rails 3.2.11

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mongoid

Following statement in my javascript is giving an error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

var js_obj = <%= @object.to_json %>;

@object is a mongoid object from the controller.

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you put the output of @object.to_json ?

Comment: {&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;510fb1a07fe2b9fe6b000012&quot;,&quot;background_color&quot;:&quot;#ffebcd&quot;,&quot;border_color&quot;:null,&quot;border_radius&quot;:null,&quot;border_style&quot;:null,&quot;border_weight&quot;:null,&quot;color&quot;:null,&quot;font_family&quot;:null,&quot;font_size&quot;:null,&quot;font_weight&quot;:null,&quot;global_note_theme_id&quot;:null,&quot;margin&quot;:null,&quot;note_id&quot;:&quot;510fb1a07fe2b9fe6b00000b&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:null}

Comment: Silly thing to post such an issue...Problem solved.....had to use <%= raw @object.to_json %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
var js_obj = <%= @object.to_json %>;
```

Use as

```
var js_obj = <%= @object.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

as to_json escapes html entities .html_safe method will solve this problem